# How to transfer data from gridview to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose if I say I have selected a row in gridview and want that row to come up in to their respective textboxes. For example, I have selected a row which has First Name and Last Names and on selection of row, the data from gridview should come in to textbox on winform. Please tell me.

I am guess it is something based on selection changed event if I am right ? Like below:

```
private void dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = txtFirstName.Text;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, your solution is to use `DataGridView.SelectedRows Property` along with `DataGridView.SelectionChanged Event`

> DataGridView.SelectedRows Gets the collection of rows selected by the
>   user.
>
> DataGridView.SelectionChanged occurs whenever cells are selected or
>   the selection is canceled, whether programmatically or by user action.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
        //Send the first cell value into textbox'
        Txt_FirstName.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString; // or row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value;
          }
    }
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Works great! Thank you MuhammadHani